# Is there a way to create a session on snow with SSO without the Browser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have developed an application in python that connects to snowflake and upload some results of a data model. The point is, If I'm the user running, no problem with the browser option. But eventually we gonna need to rollout this model to other users and we are going to face issues.

Is there a way out of this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have configured Snowflake to use single sign-on (SSO), you can configure your client application to use SSO for authentication

Check the documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#using-single-sign-on-sso-for-authentication)